# Foreign key violations with SERIAL in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, cockroachdb

While following the [cockroachdb example](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/build-a-nodejs-app-with-cockroachdb-sequelize.html) for building an app using the [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) orm for node.js, I expanded upon it to add associations between my models. Primary keys are INT with auto-increment via unique_rowid(). Based on your documentation, this is your implementation of [SERIAL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/serial.html).

After synching my models, I attempt to create records using the following code:

```
models.sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(function () {
    return models.Customer.create({
      name: "Sample Customer"
    })
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    const id = parseInt(result.dataValues.id, 10)
    return models.Order.bulkCreate([
      { subtotal: 100.00, customer_id: id },
      { subtotal: 200.00, customer_id: id }
    ])
  })
```

When this is run, I get "`error: foreign key violation: value [255737842446434300] not found in customers@primary [id]`"

I realize my [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) doesn't appear to have the precision required in order to take the string id returned from the customer creation, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update, 6 July 2017.**

The latest version of [sequelize-cockroachdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cockroachdb), v1.0.2, teaches Sequelize to coerce strings used in numeric contexts into CockroachDB integers. Simply don't call `parseInt` on `result.dataValues.id` and it should work as you expect!

```
models.sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(function () {
    return models.Customer.create({
      name: "Sample Customer"
    })
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    return models.Order.bulkCreate([
      { subtotal: 100.00, customer_id: result.dataValues.id },
      { subtotal: 200.00, customer_id: result.dataValues.id }
    ])
  })
```

---

The problem, as you've discovered, is that IDs generated by `unique_rowid()`, like 255737842446434300, are too large to fit in a [JavaScript Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), which can only exactly represent integers up to 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. The usual solution to this problem is
to use strings instead. That is, you could simply elide the call to `parseInt` and pass `{ ..., customer_id: "255737842446434300"}` directly to `Order.bulkCreate`.

Unfortunately, Sequelize will then generate a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id) VALUES ('255737842446434300');
```

PostgreSQL will happily convert that string literal into an `int8`, but CockroachDB will complain about using a string literal where an `int8` is expected. I have open PRs to fix this on either the [CockroachDB side](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pull/15903) or the [Sequelize adapter side](https://github.com/cockroachdb/sequelize-cockroachdb/pull/2), but neither has landed yet. We'll almost certainly have a solution for v1.1, however!

---

In the meantime—particularly if you want a solution compatible with CockroachDB v1.0—you can work around the issue by using UUID primary keys with the `Sequelize.BLOB` type.